# Azure Ubuntu VM, cannot access port 8080 even with ufw disabled and inbound rule added for this port

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am unable to access an azure Ubuntu VM's web app on port 8080. The VM is linked to a Virtual Network, where the network security group has inbount rules configured for 8080, and the ubuntu firewall has been disabled(ufw).

Here are the details:

1. The VM :
   [image]
2. The allowed rules for port 8080 in the network security group :
   [image]
3. The firewall has been disabled on the vm :

[image]

4. Any request to http://publicipaddress:8080/service does not work :

[image]

Please advise what else is required to make it work.

The request however works if an inbound rule of allow-all (*) is added instead of a particular port (8080), which defeats the purpose of security.

Thanks, Cheers
-Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake of wrongly configuring the nsg ingress to match the port number (eg : 8080) instead of matching the source port to *.

The protocol - source and destination host:port combination where therefore wrongly setup.

It all works now after correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, here are some possible reasons:

- Your application or service is not listening on the correct port 8080 for Foreign Address `0.0.0.0:*`. You could try to run the command `sudo netstat -alpn | grep LISTEN` on the Azure VM to validate it. If not, you could find what's real IP of the application consumed.
- Your Azure VM is associated with some other NSGs. You could check if there is an extra subnet level or network interface level from `virtual machine --- networking`.
- Try to remove the custom Outbound security rules in your NSG.
  [image]

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Hi @NancyXiong, i've added a reply with pictures as part of another "answer" post below, as the comment does not allow adding of images.

Comment: What's the application on that Azure VM? Can you `curl http://localhost:8080/say/hello` from that Azure Ubuntu VM?

Comment: If you change to use another machine, from the machine, don't you still access an azure Ubuntu VM's web app on port 8080?

Comment: So, it's the wrong NSG configuration. If my reply helps you point it out, you should accept my reply. Also, your providing screenshots did not give the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nancy,

1. The output of the netstat command is :
   [image]

It appears that the port 8080 is listening to all addresses (but maybe on IPv6?)

2. The VM and the NSG are part of the same group :
   [image]

the resource group:
[image]

3. Did remove the outgoing rules, but it still does'nt work :(.

Not sure what else am i missing.